# how do i reset my raspberry pi using the terminal

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, terminal, raspberry-pi-os, reset

How do i reset my raspberry pi using terminal? I don't have access to another PC so i have to reset using only the raspberry pi. I have tried searching up answers but no-one seems to not have another pc.
(edit): by reset i mean fully factory reset as though im re-installing debian.

Comment: Could you edit your question and explain what you mean by reset?  What is reset meant to do?

Comment: i mean fully factory reset as though im re-installing debian

Answer (score 1):

Installing software does not affect the state of the Pi.  All the state is held on the SD card.

To re-install Debian you need to write a fresh image to the SD card (or just insert an SD card with a different image).

Answer (score 0):

The ONLY way is to install a fresh image.

This requires a computer and SD Card writer.

This can be any computer including the Pi. I routinely write to SD using the Pi.